# Retrieving data using relationships in Yii PHP

Tags: php, yii, foreign-key-relationship

Hi I have a database where i use a link table to link products and categories.

The relationships look like this:

```
Product      ProductCategories       Category
Id           Id                      Id
Name         ProductId               Name   
             CategoryId
```

So the productCategory table links Products to Categories

My problem is when im trying to find all Products under the category with the Id of 1

I use this code but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
$models = Products::model()->with('productcategories')->findByPk(1);
```

This is the Products Relationships:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'productcategories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Productcategories', 'ProductId'),
    );
}
```

Comment: How is the relationship defined in the model?

Comment: What is not working? Does it not return anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'productcategories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Productcategories', 'ProductId'),
        'Categories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Category', '',
            'through'=>'productcategories',
            'on' => 'Categories.Id = productcategories.CategoryId',
        ),
    );
}

// Get all Product with a Category with id = 1
$models = Products::model()->with('Categories')->findAll('Categories.Id = 1');
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me out. However I did not need the Categories relationship (I may however use it in the future). The code i finally used was:

$models = Products::model()->with('productcategories')->findAll('productcategories.Id = 1');

Comment: ohh I understand now.. I hope that this will be help you.